# Probabilistic Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: algorithm, math

Consider the following algorithm.

```
function Rand():
    return a uniformly random real between 0.0 and 1.0

function Sieve(n):

    assert(n >= 2)

    for i = 2 to n
        X[i] = true

    for i = 2 to n
        if (X[i])
            for j = i+1 to n
                if (Rand() < 1/i)
                    X[j] = false

    return X[n]
```

What is the probability that Sieve(k) returns `true` as a function of k ?

Comment: `return true` is a bit ambigious. Do you mean returns the boolean value `true` or return a true (correct) answer?

Comment: This question should be asked in [math](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: It is also an algorithm question so I decided to ask here.

Comment: You will find the answer more quickly on math Q&A site, because it requires math.

Comment: The title is a little misleading: this looks nothing like the sieve of Eratosthenes. That one would start `j` from `2*i` and increment it by `i` at each step. Is that what you meant to write, or is the algorithm you posted correct and the sieve of Eratosthenes has nothing to do with it?

Comment: @IVlad: There was a bug, it should have been 1/i rather than 1/j.  The relationship is that for each X[i] that hasn't been sieved, rather than deterministically setting `(X[2i], X[3j],...)` false, it sets all `X[j > i]` false with probability `1/i`.  This has the same expected density, so the relationship should be clear now.

Comment: May I ask for source of the problem?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171208/probabilistic-sieve-of-eratosthenes

Comment: The code needs to be modified in some way. For the case when `n=2`, `j = 3 to 2`

Comment: @nicholas: as usual this would mean that the body of the loop is not executed.

Comment: We can take it to mean that, however, it would not be a *usual* thing to do since many languages allow for reverse loops and no positive increment is specified (although implied). I would recommend rephrasing it such that either `Assert n>2` or run `for i = 1 to n`

Comment: @nicholas: Which languages are you talking about? In all of the top 5 languages (by the TIOBE index for example) if the standard for loop limits are backwards the loop will not execute (as opposed to step backwards).  The psuedo-code syntax I used is most similiar to Pascals for loop, which also has the behaviour I described.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling, `not-` tags are inappropriate on this site.  *Do not* recreate it, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's define a series of random variables recursively:

Let X<sub>k,r</sub> denote the indicator variable, taking value `1` iff `X[k] == true` by the end of the iteration in which the variable `i` took value `r`.

In order to have fewer symbols and since it makes more intuitive sense with the code, we'll just write X<sub>k,i</sub> which is valid although would have been confusing in the definition since `i` taking value `i` is confusing when the first refers to the variable in the loop and the latter to the value of the variable.

Now we note that:

P(X<sub>k,i</sub> ~ 0) = P(X<sub>k,i-1</sub> ~ 0) + P(X<sub>k,i-1</sub> ~ 1) * P(X<sub>k-1,i-1</sub> ~ 1) * 1/i

(~ is used in place of = just to make it understandable, since = would otherwise take two separate meanings and looks confusing).

This equality holds by virtue of the fact that either `X[k]` was `false` at the end of the `i` iteration either because it was false at the end of the `i-1`, or it was `true` at that point, but in that last iteration `X[k-1]` was `true` and so we entered the loop and changed `X[k]` with probability of 1/i. The events are mutually exclusive, so there is no intersection.

The base of the recursion is simply the fact that P(X<sub>k,1</sub> ~ 1) = 1 and P(X<sub>2,i</sub> ~ 1) = 1.

Lastly, we note simply that P(`X[k] == true`) = P(X<sub>k,k-1</sub> ~ 1).

This can be programmed rather easily. Here's a javascript implementation that employs memoisation (you can benchmark if using nested indices is better than string concatenation for the dictionary index, you could also redesign the calculation to maintain the same runtime complexity but not run out of stack size by building bottom-up and not top-down). Naturally the implementation will have a runtime complexity of `O(k^2)` so it's not practical for arbitrarily large numbers:

```
function P(k) {
   if (k<2 || k!==Math.round(k)) return -1;
   var _ = {};
   function _P(n,i) {
      if(n===2) return 1;
      if(i===1) return 1;
      var $ = n+'_'+i;
      if($ in _) return _[$];
      return _[$] =  1-(1-_P(n,i-1) + _P(n,i-1)*_P(n-1,i-1)*1/i);
   }
   return _P(k,k-1);
}

P(1000); // 0.12274162882390949
```

More interesting would be how the 1/i probability changes things. I.e. whether or not the probability converges to 0 or to some other value, and if so, how changing the 1/i affects that.

Of course if you ask on mathSE you might get a better answer - this answer is pretty simplistic, I'm sure there is a way to manipulate it to acquire a direct formula.

Comment: There was a bug, 1/j should be 1/i.  Please check if this effects your answer.  Sorry.

Comment: This ignores the correlations between the probabilities, but it gets remarkably close to the right answer, which according to my simulations is p (1000) = 0.1199 +- 0.0003. See [my answer at math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/171655/6622), where I derive a simpler recursion relation for the probabilities modeled as independent.